# How to jump to first row where a cell contains a certain text

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet where I've found some code that jumps to the first empty row:

```
 lastRowA = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
 ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("RO input sheet").Range("A" & lastRowA).Select
```

My problem is that the conditions surrounding the spreadsheet have changed so now I need to tweak the code so it jumps to the first row where cell A contains a specific text, for instance "Test123".

How can I do this in VBA?

Comment: `.Find.Select`. is the wrong way to do it. It is prone to errors. What if the search string is not found?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Replace the entire code with simply:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("RO input sheet").Columns(1).Find("Test123").Select
```

Comment: A colleague asked me how to find a row with given criteria and update a subsequent column on that row, so I took this and edited it to `.find("thing").offset(0, n).formula = "=blah"`. They were bowled over by the resulting technological marvel. Thanks!

Comment: Why do you have `.Columns(1)` in here?

Comment: Find needs to be used on a Range to search in, in this case all of column 1 (A). But it can be changed to any range.